# Call a function from an *ngIf Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Say I have this code here

```
<div *ngIf="item">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Is there a way I can call a function if that *ngIf evaluates to true??

you know something like this..

```
<div *ngIf="(item) : callFunction() ? ...">lorem ipsum</div>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else

Comment: Try `*ngIf="condition && yourfunction()"`. Your function must return true to the if evaluate to true, but it will only be executed if your condition is true, since an `and` operator will stop on first false.

Comment: Can you give some more context of what you are trying to do?  Otherwise the answer is to just add a check to ngOnCheck

Comment: I would advise against this. 
This is very bad practice and will cause serious performance issues in your codebase. 
Instead use a Boolean variable in your templates. Calling a method will result in multiple calls, every time change detection occurs. In one of my apps, it called the method over 4,000 times, before resolving:

https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Angular way would be:

`<div *ngIf="name; then func(); else false">;</div>`

But as `*ngIf` evaluates passed in logical expression, you can also do:

`<div *ngIf="name?func():false">;</div>`

Comment: The first solution was calling func() for me in an infinite loop even though my if condition was not met. In my case it was <div *ngIf="name=='text'; then testFu()" >Show this</div>

Even though name did not equal 'text'

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<div *ngIf="item ===true?callFunction():'otherStuff'">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

**Html**

```
<div *ngIf="item; then callfunction; else nofunction"></div>
<ng-template #callfunction>
  {{call()}}
</ng-template>
<ng-template #nofunction>
 <!-- something else -->
</ng-template>
```

**Ts**

```
call(){
}
```

If you got better solution than this please post that to