# execute a function after a div in ngIf?

Tags: angular

When I click `Button1` it would set `varX`, also "eventually" call `loadValues()`.
But the function `loadValues()` accesses element `<div  id="foo" >` , so `loadValues` should be called after `<div  id="foo" >`, else it would result in `Error:HTML container not found` . How to execute a function after a div in ngIf?

-* my-component.ts *-

```
setVarX(){
  this.varX=true;
     
}
loadValues(){
}
```

-* my-component.hmtl *-

```
<button type="button" (click)="setVarX()">Button1</button>
        <ng-container *ngIf="varX">
            <div  id="foo" ></div>
            //loadValues() to be called now
        </ng-container>
```

I tried using `ngAfterViewChecked` but it is being called multiple (indefinite) times:

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    this.loadValues();      
}
```

Comment: The problem is that your button is still displaying as it doesn't have a *ngIf condition on it, clicking it will cause the setVarX() function to execute and it has this.loadValues() function.

Comment: I found out, I could remove the `loadValues` from `setVarX()`. Now I can call `loadValues` independently, so it should be called every time after  `<div  id="foo" ></div>` . How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a utility of `waitUntil` that resolves a promise when an operation is completed.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const waitUntil = async (untilTruthy: Function): Promise<boolean> => {
  while (!untilTruthy()) {
    await interval(25).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  }
  return Promise.resolve(true);
};
```

```
async setVarX(){
  this.varX=true;
  await waitUntil(() => !!document.getElementById('foo')); // wait until foo element is 
  // on screen before doing loadValues
  this.loadValues(); //-> but actually this function should be called after Div in *ngIf="varX"    
}
```

If you don't want to use `document`, you can use `@ViewChild` like so:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
....
@ViewChild('foo') foo: ElementRef; // declare variable

async setVarX(){
  this.varX=true;
  await waitUntil(() => !!this.foo); // wait until foo element is 
  // on screen before doing loadValues
  this.loadValues(); //-> but actually this function should be called after Div in *ngIf="varX"    
}
```

And your HTML will change to have a template variable on the foo div

```
<button type="button" (click)="setVarX()">Button1</button>
        <ng-container *ngIf="varX">
            <div  id="foo" #foo></div> // add #foo here
            //loadValues() to be called now
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: I found out, I could remove the `loadValues` from `setVarX()`. Now I can call `loadValues` independently, so it should be called every time after  `<div  id="foo" ></div>` . How can I do that?

Comment: I think it will be the same. Clicking on the button will set varX to true, we wait until the foo element is on the screen, then we call loadValues.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the this.loadValues() function out of the setVarX() function in .TS file and call it like this in HTML file

```
<div *ngIf="varX?loadValues():false">;</div>
```

[Call a function from an *ngIf Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642243/call-a-function-from-an-ngif-angular-5)

Comment: return of `loadValues()` could not be assigned to `ngIf`